# Filter Rows returned from SQL Query by XML type field using Xquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery

I have a table that stores data about errors that occur (via SSIS) , the main column that has information is stored as XML. I want to be able to query name/value pairs in this column.

To explain in SQL: `SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE seq='7406834'`

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(id INT, category varchar(10), details xml)

    INSERT INTO #tmp(id,category,details) values (1,'cat1','<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406815" /></fields>')  
    INSERT INTO #tmp(id,category,details) values (1,'cat2','<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406817" /></fields>')  
    INSERT INTO #tmp(id,category,details) values (1,'cat3','<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406834" /></fields>')  
    INSERT INTO #tmp(id,category,details) values (1,'cat4','<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406841" /></fields>')

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Can anyone help with syntax.  I have been able to essentially use a derived table, making each element into a column, and then query that, but it seems there should be a more simplistic way to say give me all the attributes (id, category, details) for each row  that have a details.seq='xxxxx'.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my mind, and used FLWOR :P

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
      id INT
    , category VARCHAR(10)
    , details XML
    )

INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( id
        , category
        , details
        )
VALUES  ( 1
        , 'cat1'
        , '<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406815" /></fields>'
        )
INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( id
        , category
        , details
        )
VALUES  ( 1
        , 'cat2'
        , '<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406817" /></fields>'
        )
INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( id
        , category
        , details
        )
VALUES  ( 1
        , 'cat3'
        , '<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406834" /></fields>'
        )
INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( id
        , category
        , details
        )
VALUES  ( 1
        , 'cat4'
        , '<fields><field name="brnum" value="586" /><field name="qty" value="0" /><field name="seq" value="7406841" /></fields>'
        )

DECLARE @val INT = 7406834 


SELECT  *
FROM    #tmp t
WHERE   details.value('(for $f in //field
                        where data($f/@name) = "seq"
                        return 
                          data($f/@value))[1]', 'int') = @val


DROP TABLE #tmp
```